# How to have a Class.SubClass.SomeMethod structure?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

This is my main class (it uses a subclass:)

```
import SubClass from './SubClass'

class MainClass extends classes(SubClass) {
  constructor () {
    // some code
  }
}

window.MainClass = new MainClass()
export default MainClass
```

This is the subclass:

```
class SubClass {
  constructor () {
    this.someMethod = function () {
      // some code
    } 
  }
}

export default SubClass
```

If I want to use a method from the SubClass I can write: `MainClass.someMethod`.

How to modify this code so I write: `MainClass.SubClass.someMethod` instead?

So I can write:

`MainClass.SubClass.someMethod`
`MainClass.SubClass2.someMethod`

In case I need another SubClass?

Comment: Where is `classes()` defined?

Comment: It's unclear what is the relationship between these classes and where exactly MainClass.SubClass.someMethod MainClass.SubClass2.someMethod should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call `super()`. And `classes()` seem doen't need to be added.

When used in a constructor, the `super` keyword appears alone and must be used before the `this` keyword is used.
See [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

```
import SubClass from './SubClass'

class MainClass extends SubClass {
  constructor () {
    super();
    console.log(this.someMethod)
  }
}
```

Hope this help